# iOS content management system

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS programming and am starting my first project. I'm wondering how clients manage the content (blogs, videos, etc) on their apps after you deliver the final product. Is their a content management system I should be implementing or do the developers usually handle that?

Answer (score 1):

A developer would build it from scratch. An alternative to starting from the ground up would be to use CloudKit or some other NoSQL based web service to manage the content. Couchdb, Firebase, etc...

A client might add content in several ways. One could create a simple web form that allows a client to edit the content (empty form to add, a table with a link to edit or delete). If the client has a developer account you could add their Apple ID as a role to the CloudKit database with specific security rights to edit that database. Similar activities would apply to other platforms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. So if I build it from scratch which I plan on doing, how would my client add new blog posts or videos later on? Would they just send me the content and I would add it for them?